# It is possible to use python's default help function In PDB?

Tags: python, ipython, pdb

When in PDB sessions, the function "help" gets overridden to show help on just debugger commands rather being able to do what the default python help function can do. Is there a way to access the original help function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an exclamation mark before the line to run:

```
(Pdb) !help(urllib2)
```